# How do I <use> a named <tspan> element in an SVG document?

Tags: svg

I'm trying to define a `tspan` early in an SVG document so it can be transcluded later inside a `text`. At least in Firefox, the following code does not produce this result.

```xml
<svg version="1.1" width="500" height="500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs>
        <tspan id="transcluded-text">This is a text</tspan>
    </defs>
    <text>
        <use href="#transcluded-text"/>
    </text>
</svg>
```

Using Firefox's Inspect tool, the `use` element contains a shadow DOM (`#shadow-root`) as expected, but the shadow DOM itself is empty.

**Without using Javascript**, is it possible to transclude a `tspan` inside a `text` like this?

Comment: You don't. A <use> element is not a valid child of a <text> element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [text](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/text#usage_notes) element can only contain text content child elements (so, not `<use>`) and the only text related element the [defs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/defs#usage_notes) element can contain is `<text>`. So, it all points to that the `<tspan>` cannot be used in this way.

```html
<svg version="1.1" width="500" height="500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <text x="10" y="20" font-size="20" id="transcluded-text">This is a text</text>
  </defs>
  <use href="#transcluded-text"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you can not use `<use>` elements **within** a `<text>` element;
or a bare `<tspan>` within `<defs>`

A modern *Native* Web Component can do the *replace* job:

(this will cause a FOUC you might want to deal with)

```html
<script>
  customElements.define("svg-use-replacer", class extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
      setTimeout(() => { // make sure SVG is parsed
        this.querySelectorAll('use').forEach(use => {
          let href  = use.getAttribute("href");
          let tspan = this.querySelector(href);
          use.replaceWith(tspan); // .replaceWith was not available in IE
        });
        // if the bare <svg> is required in the DOM:
        // this.replaceWith(this.querySelector("svg"));
      });
    }
  });
</script>

<svg-use-replacer>
  <svg version="1.1" width="500" height="500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs>
      <tspan id="foo" stroke="green">Wonderful</tspan>
    </defs>
    <text x="10" y="20" font-size="20">
      Hello
      <use href="#foo" /> Web Component
    </text>
  </svg>
</svg-use-replacer>
```

##### Notes

- The oldskool way is to attach a *class* and **after that Element is parsed** run JavaScript on it.
- With Web Components it totally does **not matter *WHEN*** the Web Component is defined.
  You can execute the above `script` any time you want.